# Angular2 : TypeError: p is undefined in system.src.js ON FIREFOX

Tags: node.js, firefox, typescript, angular, angular2-template

i'm Running under angular2 beta 12 my app , it works perfectly on Chrome , but on Firefox it crashes and shows continuously `"Loading..."`

i was told that it's a problem in firefox polyfills .

any propositions ?

By the way this is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Minuiserie SIFAST</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ng2-material/dist/ng2-material.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ng2-material/dist/font.css">


    <!-- Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>





    <!--importer ici les js de jquery-->

    <script src="./dev/resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./dev/resources/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>



    <script src="./dev/jqueryLibs/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./dev/jqueryLibs/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>




    <!--importer ici la js de bootstrap-->
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


    <!--Importer ici hammer.js-->
    <script src="dev/jqueryLibs/hammer/hammer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>
<body>
<app>Loading...</app>

<script>
    System.config({

        //use typescript for compilation
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        //typescript compiler options
        typescriptOptions: {
            emitDecoratorMetadata: true,

        },
        //map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            "ng2-material":"node_modules/ng2-material"




        },


        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'ng2-material': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }

    });
    System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>


 </body>
```

TSCONFIG:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./app"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./dev/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": true
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors in the console ??

Comment: Do you want to use the typescript compiler in the browser (runtime)? Because if you do, you should change the format to `esm` and  the defaultExtension to `ts` in the `app` package

Comment: in cnsole  of  firefox only one error and it s the title of question : type ertor is undefined in system.src

Comment: no i wont , luke that my app runs on chrome but in gitegox it crashes and i wanna fix that

Comment: Then why do you add the typescript library and have typescript options in your systemjs config

Comment: yeah u can say that tag script is out of my need , but i think that the problem is not in relation with it , i deleted it by the way and the problem persists , i read in forums abour problem on polyfills with firefox but i have no idea how to resolve it , the problem of p undefined comes from a function "split! in system.src.js

Comment: @firasKoubaa (use @username, otherwise I won't get a message) The error is in the `readMemberExpression` function. Remove the typescript transpiler options from the system config and im sure it will work

Comment: @PierreDuc  ok i have removed the typescript transpiler option :, but the problem persists

Comment: @PierreDuc i hav exactly removed the tag script of typescript and i have also removed the transpiler options from the script of system.config , but on running , it still work on chrome and throw the same error in firefox

Comment: @firasKoubaa Can you post your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Because there is something going wrong compiling the TypeScript to JavaScript

Comment: @PierreDuc ; of course

Comment: @PierreDuc i ve already updated the question and posted my tsconfig file after the index.html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue was declared of as a firefox issue for version under 44

i simply depassed this probleme by using firefox 46 or firefox developer 47